# How to use calibration plots and probability distribution to improve a classification model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have been working on a classification problem. With different classifiers [see figure below], the AUC scores I achieve ranges between `0.79-0.80`, which is not very bad. However, I am trying to improve the performance of the classifier. To get some leads on how to do this, I have generated the following visualizations using [this tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py). Extra Trees seem to be the best. But, I do not know how to move forward after this point. For example, can I inform a [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) using this figure? If so, how? I appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: I was also reading sklearn doc about `Probability calibration` recently! I do not think if it can help you to improve the performance of your models. Rather it just gives you a more reliable probability estimation (kind of adjusting the prior probability). As the document says, for instance if the probability estimate of your classifier is about 0.8, then you can be more confident that approximately 80% actually belong to the positive class. While as the doc suggests randomforest overestimate this probability. Hope my comment helps and also please share with us if you have any breakthrough!

Comment: @MhFarahani thanks! Is your comment based on the second graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ROC_AUC score is sensitive only to the *order* of probabilities, not to their absolute values. Literally, if you divide all your probabilities by 2, ROC_AUC score will *not* change.

This means, probability calibration is useless for improving AUC. You have to resort to different methods. I don't know what you tried already,  the list may include

- feature engineering
- feature selection
- GridSearch for optimal hyperparameters

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I have applied all the methods you listed already. I think I am stuck at 0.8 AUC level. The problem is that the variable I am trying to predict is influenced by an external factor about which I have no information. I guess, that is all I can do.

Comment: @renakre this is the correct answer, give lanenok the sweet green checkbox :)

Comment: @sapo_cosmico I did :)